# Creating constructor in another class

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a partial class with no constructor code. I want to add constructor code but is it possible to add this constructor in another class which is a part of this partial class.

Comment: It is a partial class auto-generated using T4 template but there is no constructor code. I want to add a constructor to this class but I want this new class to be located in another folder.

Comment: @RPK, add the new cs file in the folder, name the class as `public partial class <yourclass>` and make sure you specify the same namespace as in generated class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a constructor to a partial class, *if* your class is partial to that class!

Here's an example of what you can do:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Test(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}

public partial class Test
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Test(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Essentially this would be the same as doing:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Test(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Test(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem. The other partial class (with Constructor) is also with the same name but I am unable to access the properties of old partial class. While creating instance, it is red-underlined.

Answer (score 3):

> add this constructor in another class

No, you can't.

But in the same partial class or may be on a different file, yes

```
public partial class Test
{
}

public partial class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: So this means another partial class with the same name.

Comment: +1. @RPK, no it means the same class implemented in separate files by using `partial` to split implemetation between files.

Comment: partial class is a single class, split over multiple source files or same file like above, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add constructor for a class in another class.

What is possible it to have constructor for a class that consist from several files wiht partial class in any of the files for this partial class.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question correctly, the answer is that you can add the constructor in any side of the partial class you wish. But you cant add it in a nested class that exists in your partial class, as that is a totally different class. Examples are provided on the official msdn site that make it clear.